# How to link static library and google tests with cmake

Tags: c++, cmake, googletest

I'm trying to link my project with google C++ testing framework. I have this directory structure:

```
-- GeKon --- gekon (where my project is)
         |-- tests -- lib (google test)
```

The project structure is supposed to replicate this example from creators of CLion: 
[Calendar](https://github.com/anastasiak2512/Calendar)

CMakeFiles have this content:

**root CMakeFile**

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.8)
project(Gekon)
include_directories(gekon)
add_subdirectory(gekon)
add_subdirectory(tests)
```

**gekon CMakeFile**
(Few lines were omitted to make it shorter)

```
project (gekon)
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)
set(HEADER_FILES ...)
set(SOURCE_FILES gk_functions.cpp)
add_executable(gekon_run main.cpp ${SOURCE_FILES} ${HEADER_FILES})
target_link_libraries(gekon_run ${OpenCV_LIBS})
add_library(gekon STATIC ${SOURCE_FILES} ${HEADER_FILES})
```

**tests CMakeFile**

```
project(gekon_tests)
add_subdirectory(lib)
include_directories(${gtest_SOURCE_DIR}/include ${gtest_SOURCE_DIR})
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)
add_executable(runGekonTests first_test.cpp)
target_link_libraries(runGekonTests gtest gtest_main)
target_link_libraries(runGekonTests gekon)
target_link_libraries(runGekonTests ${OpenCV_LIBS})
```

But I'm still getting an error from linker, that it cannot find reference to the function:

```
CMakeFiles/runGekonTests.dir/first_test.cpp.o: In function `fitness_mse_test_test_equal_Test::TestBody()':
/path/tests/first_test.cpp:32:undefined reference to `gekon::fitness_mse(gekon::tr_sample_t, cv::Mat)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
tests/CMakeFiles/runGekonTests.dir/build.make:135: recipe for target 'tests/runGekonTests' failed
gmake[3]: *** [tests/runGekonTests] Error 1
```

I've also tried few suggestions from StackOwerflow like this one:
[How do I tell CMake to link in a static library in the source directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14077611/how-do-i-tell-cmake-to-link-in-a-static-library-in-the-source-directory)
but still no success.

What should I do to make it work?

The project source code is here:

[Project source on GitHub](https://github.com/argorain/GeKon)

---

```
cmake version 3.4.1
gcc version 5.3.1
```

---

**Solution**

The problem was neither in the cmakefile nor in tests. My *.cpp file was wrong. Instead of `namespace gekon {...}` I was using `using namespace gekon`.

Comment: Did you try to pass the link libraries in a single command? `target_link_libraries(runGekonTests gekon gtest gtest_main ${OpenCV_LIBS})`. Seems more like an error related to link your own library instead of gtest. Also I took a short llook into your repo and you could include gtest as git submodule: `git submodule add https://github.com/google/googletest.git`

Comment: I did, but it's still the same. Yes, the problem is with linking my library, maybe I chose confusing name for the question. Anyway thanks for the submodule, I replaced the readme file with it.