# open cv build with cmake can't find libjpeg

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake

i download `opencv 3.1.0` and build it with cmake i unchecked `BUILD_SHARED_LIBS`

after building finish i try to compile an c++ code as static lib and this is my

`CMakeListed.txt` file

```
    cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)                     
   PROJECT(word)              
   set(OpenCV_DIR "/home/medozeus/videos/opencv/share/opencv")                     
   FIND_PACKAGE( OpenCV REQUIRED )                               
   INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES( ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS} )
   ADD_EXECUTABLE(wordx main.cpp)                          
   TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES (wordx ${OpenCV_LIBS})
```

its compiled without error and i run the program also without error but when i send the program to another pc and run it its give me

> error while loading shared libraries: libjpeg.so.8: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

this is my `3rdparty` folder content after build

[image]

and the lib inside `3rdparty` content

[image]

but the source code have all the library i don't know why when i build it only build one library in 3rdparty mabye this cause the error

> error while loading shared libraries: libjpeg.so.8: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

this is my `3rdparty` folder content in source code of open cv

[image]

any idea

Comment: Check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14077611/how-do-i-tell-cmake-to-link-in-a-static-library-in-the-source-directory

Answer (score 3):

The error means there is no libjpeg.so.8 file on target machine you are running your executable. You could try installing it:

`sudo apt-get install libjpeg-dev`

Comment: Just to add a little bit more to your answer, OpenCV has quite a lot of dependencies (a lot of them optional), but I will suggest @medo to take a look to this [tutorial](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/10/24/ubuntu-16-04-how-to-install-opencv/) to the part of the dependencies, to be able to install the most used ones