# CMake adding files with ends with "*.a"

Tags: cmake

My compile command is:

```
cc -std=c11 -I include src/main.c lib/libflatccrt.a -o run_file
```

Which has to have`lib/libflatccrt.a` init to compile. How do you add this file to CMake?
Right now my CMakeLists.txt is:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.6)
project (MyProject)
include_directories(include)
file(GLOB SOURCES "src/*.c")
add_executable(MyProject ${SOURCES})
```

Comment: adding to my end of a CMakeLists.txt file, this command:
target_link_libraries(MyProject lib/libflatccrt.a)
"cmake" would compile, but "make" command says: cannot find -llib/libflatccrt.a

Comment: You need to provide absolute path to the library, like in that question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14077611/how-do-i-tell-cmake-to-link-in-a-static-library-in-the-source-directory.

Comment: Yes, I did provide exact path to it and now it does find it. Thank you!